# .pm file that's loaded on every invocation of the perl interpreter?

Tags: perl

I thought I remember reading somewhere about where perl can be configured to automatically load a certain `.pm` file on start up.

I know about `PERL5OPT`, but to my recollection, this was a specific file that would be loaded if it exists.

Is it a compile option that can be set (i.e. via `Configure`)?

Comment: What are you planning to load?

Comment: since you asked - I am creating a version of perl for development which will load in all of the things that I find I need, e.g. things like: `Data::Dumper`, `read_file` (from `File::Slurp`), etc. These will be available in the package main, so I can always refer to them using `::...`.

Comment: user5402, just use ToolSet. You can load a customized set or sets of modules with one import - http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ToolSet

Comment: this may seem lame, but I don't even want to type 'use whatever' at the top of my file :-)

Comment: I would recommend against using `sitecustomize.pl` for that purpose.  It will add cost to *every* use of perl, even unrelated system programs.  It will pollute the main namespace of every use of perl causing hard to track down bugs.  Your code will be difficult to maintain for the next person as it relies on an invisible module being loaded.  Finally, since it relies on a magic system-wide global config, you will be unable to port your code to another machine without polluting it, too.  Type the use line and keep it package/lexically scoped.  See also perl5i.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading through perldoc perlrun it looks like you are looking for what is talked about in the -f option:

> -f
>
> Disable executing $Config{sitelib}/sitecustomize.pl at startup.
>
> Perl can be built so that it by default will try to execute
>   $Config{sitelib}/sitecustomize.pl at startup (in a BEGIN block). This
>   is a hook that allows the sysadmin to customize how Perl behaves. It
>   can for instance be used to add entries to the @INC array to make Perl
>   find modules in non-standard locations.
>
> Perl actually inserts the following code:
>
> ```
> BEGIN {
> do { local $!; -f "$Config{sitelib}/sitecustomize.pl"; }
> && do "$Config{sitelib}/sitecustomize.pl";
> }
> ```
>
> Since it is an actual do (not a require), sitecustomize.pl doesn't
>   need to return a true value. The code is run in package main , in its
>   own lexical scope. However, if the script dies, $@ will not be set.
>
> The value of $Config{sitelib} is also determined in C code and not
>   read from Config.pm , which is not loaded.
>
> The code is executed very early. For example, any changes made to @INC
>   will show up in the output of `perl -V`. Of course, END blocks will be
>   likewise executed very late.
>
> To determine at runtime if this capability has been compiled in your
>   perl, you can check the value of $Config{usesitecustomize} .

I've never done this, but it looks like if you put what you want in `$Config{sitelib}/sitecustomize.pl` you'll get what you are looking for.

See:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html
- http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2007/10/msg129926.html

Comment: Where can I read on the %Config hash? Googling `perl Config hash` gets too much stuff...

Comment: @aparker42: I see, that easy %) Thank you! I'd give a second +1 if I could.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by what you mean by "on start up".  If you mean when a script / CGI / whatever is "started", then just use the module in the script:

use Data::Dumper;

Or do you mean something else?