# Perl script run via sudo couldn't find library, @INC contents changed

Tags: perl, sudo

Perl script run via sudo couldn't find library. The path containing the required library doesn't exist in @INC when running via sudo.

```
sudo perl -e "print \"@INC\""
```

prints less paths than

```
perl -e "print \"@INC\""
```

I've tried change the sudoers file by

```
Defaults    !env_reset
```

which doesn't help.

Is there a way to keep the @INC contents?

```
 Environment variables to remove:
    RUBYOPT
    RUBYLIB
    PYTHONUSERBASE
    PYTHONINSPECT
    PYTHONPATH
    PYTHONHOME
    TMPPREFIX
    ZDOTDIR
    READNULLCMD
    NULLCMD
    FPATH
    PERL5DB
    PERL5OPT
    PERL5LIB
    PERLLIB
    PERLIO_DEBUG
    JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
    SHELLOPTS
    GLOBIGNORE
    PS4
    BASH_ENV
    ENV
    TERMCAP
    TERMPATH
    TERMINFO_DIRS
    TERMINFO
    _RLD*
    LD_*
    PATH_LOCALE
    NLSPATH
    HOSTALIASES
    RES_OPTIONS
    LOCALDOMAIN
    CDPATH
    IFS

 Environment variables to preserve:
    XAUTHORIZATION
    XAUTHORITY
    TZ
    PS2
    PS1
    PATH
    LS_COLORS
    KRB5CCNAME
    HOSTNAME
    DISPLAY
    COLORS
```

Thanks for the help. The answer is:

```
 Defaults !env_reset

 Defaults env_delete-=PERLLIB
```

Comment: The behavior also depends on `env_delete` and `env_check`; do you have anything in those?  Do you see a difference which is specifically due to something in your environment (i.e. `PERL5LIB` I guess?)

Comment: You could also add `use lib "/my/directory";` to your Perl script. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#ENVIRONMENT

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for pointing out that. The env_delete and env_check are no set up in sudoers file. I updated the question description with the current "Environment variables to remove" and "Environment variables to preserve" list.

Comment: *"Are no set up"* does not really parse, and seems to be at odds with your updated question -- if your `sudo` has a large list of "Environment variables to remove" then those are being set in `env_delete` and you will not be able to pass them into the `sudo` command (unless of course you get an admin to change these settings, perhaps for a particular command etc).

Comment: Somewhat relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92998/how-can-i-keep-all-environment-vars-for-a-specific-command-in-sudo

Comment: @tripleee  I'm now using Linux version 3.19.8. The current sudoers file doesn't explicitly set up env_delete and env_check. The sudo used to work well with Linux version 3.4.91 with the same sudoers file but different remove/preserve lists. Don't know where the lists come from. I'm trying to modify the sudoers file.

Comment: The kernel version is basically of no interest whatsoever - the system calls to read files and switch user identity are ancient and very stable. The distro and `sudo` package version might be relevant, though in the end, this is going to be a local configuration problem (and as such not even properly on-topic for this site).

Comment: Thanks @Shelly for your useful edit! I've been looking everywhere for this! However, I'd like to point out a typo: It should be
```Defaults !env_reset

 Defaults env_delete-=PERL5LIB```
I believe env_delete+=PERL5LIB was added to sudo for security in this bug fix: https://www.sudo.ws/security/advisories/perl_env/
In any case, adding env_delete-=PERL5LIB to /etc/sudoers finally results in the same @INC for sudo vs user on my system.

Answer (score 1):

With the information you've provided we can really only make guesses.  The environment variable that directly affects `@INC` in your Perl script is `$PERL5LIB`.

However the most likely cause is that `$PATH` is different in the root shell and you're actually running a different Perl binary, which will have different defaults for `@INC` compiled in.  Use `which perl` and `sudo which perl` to test this theory.

To solve your problem, make sure the 'shebang' line (first line of your script) points to the Perl binary you want to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

And then in your Perl script add the library paths you need, either explicitly:

```
use lib '/opt/path/to/site/lib';
```

or relative to the location of the directory the script itself is in:

```
use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/lib";
```

Comment: How do you add missing path to @INC with `sudo perl -V`? When I update PERL5LIB in ~/.bashrc this only updates the @INC in the `perl -V` and not the sudo version of @INC

Comment: The current value of your `PERL5LIB` variable will probably not be passed through by `sudo` and your `.bashrc` won't come into play unless your sudo command is running bash (which it isn't). You could do something like: `sudo sh -c 'PERL5LIB=/path/to/lib perl -V'`

Comment: Thanks @Grant McLean, that is pretty funny that I just realized I am looking at your LibXML tutorial last few days and you where the poster of this thread.  Small world.  Hope to see your stuff while I use perl this semester for database class. :)

Comment: I tried this but is there a way to make it permanent so it shows up with 'sudo perl -V'?

Comment: If you build your own Perl you can specify what should be in @INC by default, but if you're using the system Perl the options are more limited. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051971) has one approach that could work if your system Perl is built with the relevant option enabled. Another approach is via `sudo` config - e.g.:  add `Defaults env_file=/etc/sudoers.env` to `/etc/sudoers` and `export PERL5LIB=/path/to/lib` to `/etc/sudoers.env`.

Comment: Great!  It's nice to know I can edit a sudoers and sudoers.env file that I never knew existed or you could make.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to have a wrapper script to set env:

to get the current env to write to a file, could move this file to a more appropriate location.

```
~/env_get.pl

sudo ~/env_wrapper.pl ~/test.pl


perl -e "print \"@INC\""
# this works for me, -p preserve the user ENV
sudo su -p - gliang -c 'perl -e "print \"@INC\""'
/usr/local/perl /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .
```

Details here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202383/how-to-pass-environment-variable-to-sudo-su

I have a hard time to paste, here is the demo code

https://github.com/EverydayQA/prima/tree/master/perl_tools